# Skyscanner: More expensive to buy 2 adult tickets, rather than 1?

Tags: tickets, airlines, flight-search-engines, fares

My wife and I want to visit India and decided to use Skyscanner.net as we usually do.

We obviously want to purchase our tickets together, and not separately.

If we set the number of travellers to 1, we get a price and then if we change the number of travellers to 2, we get a different, more expensive price.

Why? Is it a problem with Skyscanner?

Comment: Hmm, interesting thought. I guess we will have to book individually and if the price is the same for 2 individuals, then I guess something is amiss.

Answer (score 4):

That typically means there's only one ticket at the lower price. You can buy the tickets separately, then call the airline and ask to be seated together.